# ERROR pool.db: Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections using MySql

Tags: mysql, node.js

I just recently started seeing a bunch of `Too many connections` errors within my server.  Our application uses `Nodejs` as the backend and `MySql` for our database. I'm honestly not sure as to where these errors are coming from and/or how this began propagating, but it's becoming quite a big issue lately since my application starts becoming unresponsive after a certain period of time.  The code that I'm about to share was here before me, and I don't really quite understand if it was written properly or not.  My guess is that whoever wrote it isn't closing connections to the database correctly, and a bunch of them are just staying open and never closing, which is what I assume is causing this error.

This is our pool.js file

```
import mysql from 'promise-mysql';
import env from '../../../env.config.json';
const db = async (sql, descriptor, serializedParameters = []) => {
    return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
            //const connection = mysql.createPool({

                host: env.DB.HOST,
                user: env.DB.USER,
                password: env.DB.PASSWORD,
                database: env.DB.NAME,
                port: env.DB.PORT
            })
            if (connection && env.ENV === "development") {
                //console.log(/*"There is a connection to the db for: ", descriptor*/);
            }
                let result; 

                if(serializedParameters.length > 0) {
                    result = await connection.query(sql, serializedParameters)
                } else result = await connection.query(sql);
                connection.end();
                resolve(result);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR pool.db: " + e);
            reject(e);
        };         
    });
}

export default db;
```

We use sockets to call a db sequence like this one

```
//SaveMonthsTransactions
export const SaveMonthsTransactions = (obj) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(paperChanges))
        try {
            const callFunction = `CALL SaveMonthsTransactions('${obj}')`;
            //console.log(callFunction);
            const response = await db(callFunction, "SaveMonthsTransactions");
            //console.log(response);
            resolve(response[0]);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("ERROR createJob.SaveMonthsTransactions: " + e);
            reject(e);
        }
    });
};
```

Here are the errors I'm receiving

```
Server is up on port 3000.
(node:5316) [DEP0096] DeprecationWarning: timers.unenroll() is deprecated. Please use clearTimeout instead.
ERROR pool.db: Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections
ERROR tableMNG.selectAllTechCallLogs: Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections
(node:5316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR: Too many connections
    at Handshake.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:52:14)
    at Handshake.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Handshake.js:130:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:130:18)
    at connect (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\promise-mysql\lib\connection.js:18:33)
    at C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\promise-mysql\lib\connection.js:52:9
    at Promise._execute (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\debuggability.js:303:9)
    at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:483:18)
    at new Promise (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:79:10)
    at new connection (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\promise-mysql\lib\connection.js:51:12)
    at Object.exports.createConnection (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\promise-mysql\index.js:6:12)
    at _callee$ (C:/Users/micha/Dispatch-Council/src/imports/API/pool.js:6:44)
    at tryCatch (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\babel-polyfill\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:65:40)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\babel-polyfill\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:303:22)
    at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\node_modules\babel-polyfill\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:117:21)
    at step (C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\src\imports\API\pool.js:17:191)
    at C:\Users\micha\Dispatch-Council\src\imports\API\pool.js:17:437
(node:5316) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

These errors start occurring as soon as my application loads.  I see that it's trying to call some db methods but it looks like they are being rejected, because there are too many connections to it.

I'm really in a rut here, so if anyone could please help me understand what needs to be done so that these connections can get closed and stop breaking my application that would be awesome!  Thanks.

Comment: are you using windows or linux?

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen server is using linux.  But I'm testing it locally on windows which is where I'm able to see all these errors inside vs code.

Comment: try restarting your database.

Comment: also increase the databases connection pool.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen This usually works, but I don't want to have to keep restarting my application every day.  I need to figure out why it's not closing these connections properly.

Comment: try `connection.destroy()` instead of `connection.end()`

Comment: you could also try connection pooling, see: https://www.codota.com/code/javascript/modules/promise-mysql

Comment: also try seeing if the ending throws an error

`connection.close( err => {
      /* ... do something with all the results */
    }`

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen wouldn't connection.destroy() close the db connection completely and not reconnect to it?

Comment: yes, you should destroy it, because you are reconnecting alll the time

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen could all these connections be happening because one of my db calls is failing and leaving the connection open?  I'm just trying to figure out where in my code that this is causing all of this to happen.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen I'm still getting ```too many connections``` error even with destroy method.

Comment: did you increase the pool size??  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen increasing the pool size isn't going to help, if I increase it, then the connections will just continuously accrue and never disconnect.